# Silverstripe Elemental trouble after creating related dataobjects

Tags: silverstripe-4

Facts: SS 4.0.1, dnadesign/silverstripe-elemental 2.x-dev, php 7.1 and Zauberfisches Vagrant box Jessy Version 3

I made an Elemental Element that is a holder for single elements:

```
namespace R12page\Elements;

use DNADesign\Elemental\Models\BaseElement;
use SilverStripe\Forms\GridField\GridField;
use SilverStripe\Forms\GridField\GridFieldConfig_RecordEditor;
use SilverStripe\Versioned\Versioned;
use UndefinedOffset\SortableGridField\Forms\GridFieldSortableRows;


class ImageRasterElement extends BaseElement
{

private static $singular_name = 'Image Raster Element';

private static $plural_name = 'Images Raster Elements';

private static $description = 'Generates an Image Raster for multiple single Elements';

private static $table_name = 'ImageRasterElement';

private static $has_many = [
    'SingleElements' => SingleElement::class
];


private static $extensions = [
    Versioned::class . '.stagedversioned',
];

public function getType()
{
    return 'ImageRasterElement';
}

public function getCMSFields()
{
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

    $singleElements = $this->SingleElements();
    $singleElementGridConfig = GridFieldConfig_RecordEditor::create();
    $singleElementGridConfig->addComponent(new GridFieldSortableRows('SortOrder'));
    $singleElementGrid = GridField::create('SingleElements', 'Single Elements of this Page', $singleElements, $singleElementGridConfig);

    $fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Main',  $singleElementGrid);

    return $fields;
}
}
```

This Element has_many single Elements: they look like:

```
 namespace R12page\Elements;


 use R12page\Model\News;
 use R12page\Model\People;
 use R12page\Model\References;
 use SilverStripe\ORM\DataObject;
 use SilverStripe\Versioned\Versioned;

class SingleElement extends DataObject
{
private static $table_name = 'SingleElement';


private static $db = [
    'Reference' => 'Boolean',
    'People' => 'Boolean',
    'News' => 'Boolean',
    'SortOrder' => 'Int'
];

private static $has_one = [
    'News' => News::class,
    'People' => People::class,
    'Reference' => References::class,
    'ImageRasterElements' => ImageRasterElement::class
];

private static $summary_fields = [
    'News.Headline' => 'News',
    'People.Name' => 'People',
    'Reference.Headline' => 'Reference'
];

private static $extensions = [
    Versioned::class . '.stagedversioned',
];


}
```

Each Single Element has an has_one to a Data Object. The look like:

```
 namespace R12page\Model;

 use R12page\Elements\SingleElement;
 use SilverStripe\ORM\DataObject;
 use SilverStripe\Versioned\Versioned;

class News extends DataObject
{
private static $table_name = 'News';

private static $db = [
    'Headline' => 'Varchar',
    'SubHeadline' => 'Varchar',
    'Date' => 'Date',
    'DatePublished' => 'Date',
    'Content' => 'HTMLText',
    'IsActiv' => 'Boolean',
    'DisplayOnHomePage' => 'Boolean'
];

private static $has_one = [
    'Mobile' => Size::class,
    'Screen' => Size::Class
];

private static $has_many = [
    'SingleElements' => SingleElement::class
];

private static $owns = [
    'SingleElements'
];

private static $summary_fields = [
    'Headline' => 'Headline',
    'Mobile.Title' => 'Mobile',
    'Screen.Title' => 'Screen'
];

private static $extensions = [
    Versioned::class . '.stagedversioned',
];

}
```

So far so good. This is what it looks like in the admin Area.

[image: This is what it looks like in the admin Area]

The strange thing is if I add a single Element an try to create it i get this:[image: Screen after saving single element]

When i refresh the page i can see the content of the page and i can save it with out any problems. When if use php_debug everything looks good. I also don't have and error messages in the console which i think, are related to the problem i am having . I just get those to warnings:

[image]

But i think the warnings  should not be the problem. To be precise i get an error because a font is not loading.

Please help me debug this. I tried the hole day to get this to work. I can not identify the problem i am having.

This is the response i am getting back:

[image: response]

To me it looks okay.

This is the response from the browser networktap:
[image]

A view things i can confirm:

Elemental works on a clean install.

If i switch to live mode nothing changes.

If i try to use the content element that ships with elemental it has the same behavior.

Comment: have you reviewed all possible log files for php from the server? Could you simplify your scripts untill you get a working one? or better create only the sample element from https://github.com/dnadesign/silverstripe-elemental. Does that 100% work? you need to find where the possible error message is generated or, for example you could be using a SS that has a bug with the extension. So you need to figure are you causing the issue or is it present also with the least amount of code.

Comment: Also one thing that can cause issues is that you are running it on dev mode and PHP error levels are set to output Warnings that halt the execution.. Have you viewed with browsers debug tools what is the actual response yet from the request

Comment: Also your code has been working at some point and you are committing your work to git repo then git bisect is a nice way to figure out what commit caused the issues.

Comment: i never got to get this to work. I will set up a clean install an try what happens. 

This is from the silverstripe errorlog:

[2018-02-01 13:55:27] error-log.WARNING: E_WARNING: SilverStripe\ORM\Connect\MySQLiConnector::__destruct(): Property access is not allowed yet {"code":2,"message":"SilverStripe\\ORM\\Connect\\MySQLiConnector::__destruct(): Property access is not allowed yet","file":"/vagrant/www/vendor/silverstripe/framework/src/ORM/Connect/MySQLiConnector.php","line":132} []

But to be honest i have no idea what is going on there.

Comment: Does that happen when you do the action in the admin? E_warning issues can can be ignored (but if its your code doing you should fix it :) ) but they can prevent app from rendering screen if the PHP error output options output that directly to the response. You can set php to ingore e_warning errors or set the php not to output errors.

Comment: as a quick test you could put silverstripe to live mode and then try.. eg will it blend after that :)

Comment: If i switch to live mode nothing changes.

Comment: By know i think it is not even an elemental Problem as i used a populte task to get the data into the data base. I never realised that there is something is wrong with saving anything in the backend.

Comment: When you save, have the webdeveloper network tab open. You can see the http call to the server and get the error in the answer.

Comment: @Greg303 can you also have a peek is the response malformatted? The headers could be ok, but is there anything broken in the actual response output?

Comment: Thank you for help! I decided to start off with a clean SS 4 install and copy my modules into it. Maybe something went wrong when i updated the project from 3.6 to 4.